# How was the $o(x)$ in this formula calculated？

Tags: calculus

[image]

In this Equivalent Infinitesimal Replacement shown in the figure, there is such a formula
$$
e^{\sin^2x}-1+\sqrt{1-\cos x} \sim \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}x+o(x) \sim \sqrt\frac{1}{2}x
$$
What's the meaning of $o(x)$? How did it come about? Why can we ignore it?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LandauSymbols.html

Comment: Please [do not use image for the critical part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question.